# Eclipse: won't let me use Android SDK, wrongly claims my ADT is out of date

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, adt

I'm developing for Android with Eclipse, and all was working well until yesterday. I used Ninite to update all my stuff, including JREs and everything (pro tip: do not do that), and it restarted my computer without asking in the middle of editing my workspace.

This caused all kinds of filthy problems, but now it all works, except for Android. I've updated Android SDK and the eclipse ADT, then when I try to tell Eclipse the SDK location, it gives this error:

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 14.0.0 or
>   above.  Current version is 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431.  Please update
>   ADT to the latest version.

Now, this is an outright lie. My ADT is version 14.0.something. I've tried Help>Check for updates, it says there are no updates. I've tried Help>Install new software...>Available Software Sites and removing the ADT repo, then reinstalling ADT, and it says it failed because I already have version 14.0.whatever.

How do I convince eclipse that my ADT is up to date??

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105730/when-i-load-adt-why-do-i-receive-the-error-the-android-sdk-requires-android-dev which covers working around a bug where eclipse may fail to discover that a new version of ADT is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else with this problem, my solution was just to delete the Eclipse folder, and download a new copy from scratch. I had to then re-download all plugins including adt, which worked this time round.

Answer (score 167):

I found the answer to the problem. (I'm using Helios, but it should work anyway)

1. Goto folder /Program Files(x86)/Eclipse/Plugins/ and make sure previous older versions of com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_##... are deleted (sometimes update fails to delete because of UAC).  Keep the current desired version and complete the following.

   [image]
2. Run Eclipse as **administrator** or disable UAC temporarily. (windows 7)
3. Go to <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Install New Software</kbd>.
4. On <kbd>Work with:</kbd> type https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and press ENTER.
5. Wait for Eclipse to fetch the repository. An item named **Developer tools** will appear in the list.
   Mark it for install, press <kbd>Next</kbd> and follow the steps to install the ADT tools.
6. When finished, it will ask to restart Eclipse. Make sure you do this.
7. When Eclipse restarts, all your Android SDK packages should show up again.
8. Dont forget to resume UAC if you need it.

Comment: This was how I knew my adt was up to date - I tried this, as well as 'check for updates', but it wouldn't install anything new because I already had the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Worked fine with me as well.

Comment: Worked for me, I think the person who asked this question should accept this answer, as this is better than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: This does not work for me, because "check for updates" cannot find updates for the ADT (an error). I guess it cannot get / interpret the XML file from the site. I've seen people reporting this error before. Anyway this is frustrating that they could not improve the whole update process and require people to update the environment to android 4 while most of the devices have android 2.2 - 2.3 anyway.

Comment: I get up to installing software, and it just hangs at zero for hours on end.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks man. I had to do this after I updated my the android SDK without a GUI with this command: `~/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android update sdk --no-ui`

Comment: Had the same problem. Tried to update through Help > Check for Updates, but was getting an alert message like this:

Contacting software sites has encountered a problem

And after that the update process failed. Googled and found the solution.

You just need to add one line in eclipse.ini, which is located in Eclipse folder. Add this line to the end of the file:

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
And after that the update process went normally.

The problem lies in the fact that the upload process goes through IPv6, but the internet service provider supports IPv4.

Comment: +1 thank you! I tried all other methods around this and somehow it didn't work. Your's worked the first shot no troubles.

Comment: I got 99 problems, but now Eclipse ain't one

Answer (score 9):

An option is to manually download the ADT plugin (ADT archive) required. The page is, http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html. The page reveals ADT 18 is available at http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-18.0.0.zip. The link is closer to the bottom page. I needed 17 although 18 was the latest, so I modified the download URL, changing 18 to 17.

Select <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Install New Software</kbd> → <kbd>Add</kbd> → Choose <kbd>Archive</kbd> and select the location of the downloaded ADT archieve file, Choose <kbd>OK</kbd>.
Select the components required and proceed as required. You may get a message that the software is already installed, proceed with the installation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Robin for this answer. All other answers didn't work for me. but yours worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. My ADT in the eclipse was 8.x version. But my app required version 12 or more. So, I decided to upgrade both the Android SDK and ADT to the latest (at this time latest ADT is 17). I was able to upgrade the SDK but not the ADT. It always complained I got the versions already but I only had 8.x. The new SDK that I just upgraded would function only with ADT 14 and above. So, I had successfully broken my android development!!

The reason why I wasn't able to upgrade my ADT to the latest was because I was using Eclipse 3.5. The newer ADT versions require 3.6 or above. This small but key bit of information was really at the bottom of the error generated by Eclipse which required scrolling down (since only the top few lines of error were displayed). You typically wouldn't scroll down since these top few lines were followed by whitespace lines :). I did not scroll and I guess I wasted about a day trying to rectify this problem. But eventually I saw those 2 up/down arrows at the right of the dialog box and I scrolled down. There it clearly mentioned ADT 17 requires Eclipse runtime 3.6 and over.

So my solution was to find a suitable ADT that would work with Eclipse 3.5. Yes, tomorrow when I am in the mood, I shall upgrade to Eclipse 3.6 or 3.7 and the boat load of plugins I have :)

Answer (score 5):

I've just upgraded my Android SDK version, and had exactly the same issue.
The 'Check For updates' Eclipse command failed because, for some reasons, Android Traceview failed to update.

My solution was to : 
* Open <kbd>Eclipse</kbd> → <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>About Eclipse</kbd> .
* Click <kbd>Installation Details</kbd>.
* Here select all the android related lines, and update them one by one, restarting eclipse each time.

And finally it worked  ( even with Helios ) !

Comment: This method works. I have tried it a few seconds ago. This is way better than removing eclipse. I couldn't afford wasting my time reinstalling everything that was installed in my Eclipse. Restarting Eclipse after each update is not a big deal of the end result is success.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse:

<kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Check for Updates</kbd>.

Comment: Have tried that of course! The problem was that it then told me all my plugins and software were up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Best option is go to open eclipse ID

Then go to <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>About Eclipse</kbd> >>

> > u will find the Installation Details button click on that
> >
> > And now u can see the all anriod extension installed.
> >
> > Select all or select one by one and just click the update button.

you will get the latest version from the net.

Hope these will help you all.

Answer (score 0):

Your ADT and SDK is not up-to-date yet and Eclipse is complaining about the right stuff...

Open Android SDK Manager from toolbar and update your SDK from there. It doesn't help if you are checking Eclipse updates. Because through Eclipse you cannot check SDK updates for Android.

Button looks like this : [image]

Comment: Sadly not, I tried updating the sdk too, to no effect. Both sdk and adt were up to date, I think it was just a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hearing a common issue is that newer Android ADK versions require newer eclipse versions.  Colleagues who hit this say they installed Indigo in place of older Helios versions and were able to resolve the issue this way.  I have not yet done the same myself.