# Android SDK. Google API SDK link

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, shared-libraries, google-api, android-2.2-froyo

I'm trying to install the Google APIs so that I can use Google Maps in my application. The problem is simple: SDK Manager doesn't have the link that it needs to query the servers for libraries to install.

The links I have in Help, install new software, available software sites are : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse and http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios

What link do I need in order to properly download the Google APIs?

I cannot extend my Activity to MapActivity even though the manifest has `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"`, I have an api key, and my main.xml has the `<com.google.android.maps.MayView` tag.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: The Android SDK Manager has nothing to do with the Eclipse Install/Update dialog. What do you mean by "SDK Manager doesn't have the link that it needs to query the servers for libraries to install."? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

> The links I have in Help, install new software, available software sites are : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse and http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios

Those are for Eclipse. Eclipse is not Android.

> What link do I need in order to properly download the Google APIs?

You do not need a "link".

Step #1: Choose Window > Android SDK Manager from the Eclipse main menu

Step #2: Check the checkboxes beside any "Google APIs" you want, for different API levels

[image]

Step #3: Click the "Install packages..." button and follow the prompts, then close up the SDK Manager

Step #4: Select your desired project, and choose Project > Properties from the Eclipse main menu

Step #5: In the Properties window, choose Android, then set your build target to be one that has the Google APIs:

[image]

Comment: Is there an option for Eclipse on Linux that I have to directly enable to install Google APIs. Please look at my updated top post. I don't have the API option. My project is also 4.0.3

Comment: @MarcBrown: This should not have anything to do with Eclipse. I am running Linux, as you can see from the Ubuntu screenshots, so it is also not strictly a Linux issue. From the SDK Manager, try Packages > Reload, and see if that helps.

Comment: @MarcBrown: Try running the SDK Manager from outside of Eclipse (`android` in your `tools/` directory of the SDK). After that, I'm out of ideas, beyond having you reinstall the SDK from scratch.

Comment: I downloaded directly from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-15_r02.zip I then extracted directly to android-sdks/add-ons Restarted sdk manager and then installed the google apis. I the followed directions from top answer to update my tools from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852823/eclipse-wont-let-me-use-android-sdk-wrongly-claims-my-adt-is-out-of-date

Comment: @MarcBrown: It is very strange that you would need to do that. Hopefully, as the SDK pieces get updated, you will automatically pick up the new stuff.

Comment: I did the development tools updates and google apis 15 extraction at the same time. So, it could have actually been the result of the tools update that allowed for the install of the google apis, not the .zip extraction. Now on to my next topic post, why can't I import MapActivity.....