# Eclipse says my SDK tools are out of date when they're not

Tags: android, windows, eclipse

When I open up Eclipse it tells me that my SDK tools are out of date. Eclipse says my current version is 17 and I can update it to 20. This is a lie; when I open the SDK Manager, my SDK tool are 20.0.1. But when I open up the SDK Manager ***VIA*** Eclipse, the SDK tools  change to version 17. I already looked at [Eclipse: won't let me use Android SDK, wrongly claims my ADT is out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852823/eclipse-wont-let-me-use-android-sdk-wrongly-claims-my-adt-is-out-of-date) but it still wouldn't work. I deleted Eclipse and started fresh by downloading Eclipse and installing the Android repository(ADT) to Eclipse. No luck, still tells me SDK tools are 17. So I decided to play along and clicked "Open the SDK Manager" window in Eclipse. The Manager popped up and clicked "install 1 package" (SDK Tool). Halfway through, it stops and says the android-sdk/tools directory is locked by java.exe and cmd.exe so I opened Windows Task Manager and ended the "java.exe" process. And what do you know? My Android SDK Manager Windows just closed. How the am I was supposed update the SDK Tools if the SDK Manager is going to interfere with **itself**?

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar problem. SDK location is shown at the top of the SDK manager window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Eclipse was looking for the SDK Tools in the wrong place. Eclipse was looking for the tool in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

The ACTUAL TOOLS was in:

```
 C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

The SDK Manager will tell you where the tools are. You can tell Eclipse in the preferences (under the Windows) to look in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem. My answer was update ADT Plugin for Eclipse (Help->Check for Updates). Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. I had to "delete" SDK Build tools packages and then re-install the packages. After doing that, I could now create a new android project.

Answer (score 0):

For most, a simple update of build tool to required version suffice. As often happens, Android SDK Build-tools with compatible version is not installed.