# How to create New Android Virtual Device (AVD) on Mac?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am using android-sdk-macosx to download from the internet, then installed Android SDK 2.2 and 2.1 successfully, then I tried to create new AVD on mac, but I don't have any idea about how to create AVD.

I tried this below mentioned for your reference:

```
Fig 1.0 Create new AVD
```

[image]

```
Fig 2.0 I tried to open SDK and AVD Manager in eclipse menu Window --> Android SDK Manager
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Windows Menu , Select Preference Option so, following dialog box will appear. Just select the Android-SDK folder using Browse Button.

[image]

After doing this step click on the "Apply Button",

[image]

Now, you will be able to create new AVD in your eclipse.

Note, I have upload this image using Windows System, but i am sure, MAC has some, same kind of menu option.

Comment: I tried to follow this steps but the error comes, above i mentioned screen shot for your reference.

Comment: please help me, i spend 2 hours for this, but i didn't finish this

Comment: did you click on "Apply" Button after specifying sdk path ?

Comment: Apply button always not active

Comment: please see the above figure 4.o

Comment: Thanks for your help, now i fix this successfully

Answer (score 1):

Follow this seven steps to fix this issues:

```
1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
2. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Click OK.
4. If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).
In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
5. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
6. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
7. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to configure Eclipse to tell it where the `android-sdk-macosx` directory is (this can be done in 'Window>Preferences>Android> SDK Location".

Also, take a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Please see that fig 2.0 android-sdk-macosx

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot Fig 4.0, there's an error message at the top of the widow, which probably explains why the apply button is not available.
While the message cannot be read completely, I think it says that your version of ADT (Android Developer tools) does not match your version of the SDK : I might want to try updating both .

Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852823/eclipse-wont-let-me-use-android-sdk-wrongly-claims-my-adt-is-out-of-date), which might be about the same problem.