# When I load ADT why do I receive the error "The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version XX.X.X or above?"

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-sdk-tools

I just updated my Android SDK Tools to version 21.1. Unfortunately this is causing an error when I load the Android Developer Toolkit:

> The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.1.0 or above.
>
> Current version is 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58.
>
> Please update ADT to the latest version.

When I upgraded the SDK I was warned that I might need to upgrade ADT. I tried to do so by going to Help > Check for Updates. Unfortunately this returns a message that "No updates were found."

In case I've missed something here's a screenshot of my Android SDK Manager:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Am I missing an install package? Do I need to go about updating ADT (Eclipse) another way? Should I just download a new copy of ADT?

Comment: Go to Help->Install New Software and update Developer Tools

Comment: @SanketPandya I'm not sure you read through the question. The regular update didn't get the job done. I detail the solution I came up [in the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15105731/61654).

Comment: I get the same problem on the Mac at work. on my windows 7 PC at home it works GREEEAT !

Comment: Check out the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525595/this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-23-0-0-or-above/35719100#35719100 as a possible workaround.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

For some reason ADT (Eclipse) won't pick up on the fact that it does in fact need to be updated. Since the built in tools for updating are failing you you'll have to work around them. On the Help menu instead of selecting Check for Updates instead pick Install New Software (so Help > Install New Software).

On the Available Software screen in the Work With dropdown provide:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ if it's not already available. You should see a list of options including Developer Tools. Check everything that you want to update. In the list of checkboxes below uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software."

[image: Install New Software]

Click Next and follow the remaining onscreen prompts. You may be warned that instead of an install an update will be performed. This is okay. Once the operation is complete you will no longer receive the "The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit verxion 21.1.0 or above" error when you load ADT.

Comment: while clicking finish button,i have got an error says "installing software has encountered a problem." An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: etc.........

Comment: I fixed it by adding a new ADT Update Site URL with "https" instead of "http", as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11413732/475217

Comment: Simply using "Install New Software" instead of "Check for Updates" was the key for me.

Comment: Can you explain the reason we uncheck the "Contact all update sites" option?

Comment: @IcedDante at best I could offer speculation as it didn't work when checked, but did when not checked. My *speculation* is by in checking we are being explicit about where to get updates from.

Comment: This approach gives me the error `Only one of the following can be installed at once` followed by the current and new versions of the component I'm trying to update.