# Eclipse suddenly started to do weird things

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, nullpointerexception, lint

First of all, sorry for my bad english. 
I'm new on android but i can resolve some kind of logcat problems like classnotfoundexception ecc.
But that one, i really can't understand it.
Since a while, eclipse started to do really weird things. First, when i try to open it, it pops out a window saying "This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit 21.1.0 or above. Current version is 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58. Please update ADT to the latest version". So i click "Check for Updates" and after a while it appaers another windows where is written "no updates were found". Oh cool it asks me to update and he can't find updates.

But anyway: after i close it, it immediately appaers to me this error on the error log: 
"Unhandled event loop execution". I double click it and it appears that:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newxmlfile.NewXmlFileCreationPage.updateAvailableTypes(NewXmlFileCreationPage.java:1062)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newxmlfile.NewXmlFileCreationPage.createControl(NewXmlFileCreationPage.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Session data:

```
eclipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035
java.version=1.7.0_10
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

This is a continuation of log file C:/XXXXX
Created Time: 2013-03-23 14:54:10.477
```

I don't know what that means but looks like that's not a project's code fault himself.

Also, that first time it happened that problem, i opened the SDK manager i saw all my before downloaded files wasn't installed anymore. After i reinstalled 'em, anyway, sometimes (but for some strange reason not all the times) some sdk installed needs update (even if i updated 'em one or two days before).

But now the big problem: all my project classes reports errors: they doesn't recognize things like floatmath or opengl es matrix etc (but even silly things like a class name); and if i check classes where it looks like there aren't errors (by the image of the class in the package explorer, where it usually pop out a red cross on the left of the name of the class),  there are anyway errors and even really silly (like: @Override cannot be resolved to a type... what?!).

That's not my fault: i launched all my project several times before that annoying problem popped out and they worked absolutely fine, uh.

And a last thing: when i save something on an xml file (uh another problem: the main in the layout folder disappared...), it appaers that:

"'Running Android Lint' has encountered a problem. Failed". I click on details and it shows "Failed
java.lang.NullPointerException". If i check on the error log, it shows to me that: "failed". If i double click it, if shows me that:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.EclipseLintClient.getTargets(EclipseLintClient.java:890)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintClient.getHighestKnownApiLevel(LintClient.java:609)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver$LintClientWrapper.getHighestKnownApiLevel(LintDriver.java:1751)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.ManifestOrderDetector.visitElement(ManifestOrderDetector.java:396)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.XmlVisitor.visitElement(XmlVisitor.java:170)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.XmlVisitor.visitElement(XmlVisitor.java:209)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.XmlVisitor.visitFile(XmlVisitor.java:150)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:806)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:732)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:340)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.lint.LintJob.run(LintJob.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Session data:

```
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.productFramework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
```

So what's the problem? I tried in the way written here [When I load ADT why do I receive the error "The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version XX.X.X or above?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105730/when-i-load-adt-why-do-i-receive-the-error-the-android-sdk-requires-android-dev) , but after that the android XML disappeared like magic.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: *like: @Override cannot be resolved to a type: WTF?!* - was **WTF** necessary?

Comment: ok...ok... i edited. But that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: WTF is wrong with WTF? It perfectly expresses a certain level of incredulousness and frustration.

Comment: WTF = What a Terrible Failure, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#wtf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing happened to me. I just ended up re-installing everything from scratch, Eclipse, plus even the Android SDK (since the SDK Manager & updating from Eclipse weren't helping at all).

Nowadays, Eclipse is bundled with the Android SDK when you download it from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Once I did that re-install from scratch, letting go of my previous android sdk, and updating everything after that. Everything started working again. I'm sorry I don't have a better answer for you.