# Unable to create project in android SDK

Tags: android

I am trying to create an Android Application Project, but I have had a number of problems. As it is now, I cannot get beyond the first dialog box. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I am also reading that I have every sdk up to Android 4.1, even though I only have android 4.2, as shown in the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Additionally, when I open the android developer tools program, the following dialog box comes up:

[image]

even though, I have the Android Developer Toolkit version 21.1.0 installed on my machine, as shown by the following screen shot:

[image]

I am very confused right now. Could somebody please help me solve these problems? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Additionally, Could someone suggest some possible reason as to why I am seeing all these other SDKs when I only have Android 4.2 installed on my machine? Like I said, this is really confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holo Light Theme cannot be applied to Android 2.2. You need at least a minimum sdk of Android 3.

So either don't use Holo Theme or set you minimum to Android 3.

Edit: You may look into this instead: [Update Android SDK Tool to 22.0.4(Latest Version) from 22.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-21-1-0-from-21-0-1)

Comment: Did it work? Concerning your problem with your Android Developer Kit you may look into this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105730/when-i-load-adt-why-do-i-receive-the-error-the-android-sdk-requires-android-dev